# How to send a lot of data to a remote MySQL database

Tags: android, database, json, connection

I found here ([Send data from android to server via JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523761/send-data-from-android-to-server-via-json)) that I can send local Android database data to a remote MySQL database. 
So I tried to do that and when I send just a row it works good, but when I try to sync the 2 databases sending all rows (~200) from a local table to the remote one,  just few rows are stored.

Perhaps the Apache server can't receive too much requests, and however I need to send a row at time, wait for the remote server answer, send the following row, wait for the server answer and so on.

How I can be sure to send a request at a time and wait the server answer before sending the following request?

Comment: When you tried to send the JSON data were you sending it as POST or GET?  Also, are you sure it's not just a few rows were sent rather than just a few rows were stored?  Print the JSON to your logcat before sending to see if it is Android not sending enough rows or your server not processing them correctly.