# how to search for data in database by some keywords in android

Tags: android, android-intent

this program is for class to display the database in Listview.i want to add search for the required data in database by given keywords.How to add the code for searching in database with keywords in the same class

```
  public class DisplayActivity extends Activity
  {

private ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<String>();
private SQLiteDatabase MYdatabase;
ListView listView;
Button back;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        MYdatabase=db.getWritableDatabase();
    try {   
        Cursor c=MYdatabase.rawQuery("SELECt * FROM Student", null);
        if(c!=null)
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                    String age=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AGE"));
                    String address=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ADDRESS"));
                    arraylist.add("Name :"+name+"\n"+"Age :"+age+"\n"+"Address :"+address+"\n");

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        c.close();
        c.deactivate();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "could not create"+"or open the database");

    }
    finally
    {
        if(MYdatabase!=null)
        {
          MYdatabase.close();
        }
    }
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist));
}
public void Back(View v)
{
    Intent back=new Intent(DisplayActivity.this,DbExampleActivity.class);
    startActivity(back);
}
}
```

the following is the activity class code.
thought it ll be easy to understand

```
 public class DbExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 Button submit,select,search;
 AlertDialog di;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
 private SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement;
 private String name,age,address;
 private static final String TABLE_NAME="Student";
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    select=(Button)findViewById(R.id.detailsbutton);
    search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
    DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase=db.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteStatement=sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement("insert into "+TABLE_NAME+"(name,age,address)values(?,?,?)");
   submit.setOnClickListener(this);
   select.setOnClickListener(this);
   search.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.detailsbutton:
        Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);

        break;
    case R.id.savebutton:
        name=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString().trim();
        age=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString().trim();
        address=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText().toString().trim();

        sqLiteStatement.bindString(1, name);
        sqLiteStatement.bindString(2, age);
        sqLiteStatement.bindString(3, address);
        sqLiteStatement.executeInsert();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.searchbutton:
         Intent search=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayActivity.class);
         startActivity(search);
    default:
        break;
    }

}
}
```

What code is to be added to this to allow searching the database using keywords

Comment: you could use query like this `"SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id=" + ID`

Comment: thank you...but the keywords are typed in edittext..i dnt know how to link that...dnt mind i am new to android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    EditText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) 
    {
                     populateListView(s.toString());

                    }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

              public void populateListview(String s){

           DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
           MYdatabase = db.getWritableDatabase();

    try {   
    Cursor c=MYdatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM Student WHERE City ID '"+s+%"'", null); 
    if(c!=null)
    {
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                String age=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AGE"));
                String address=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ADDRESS"));
                arraylist.add("Name :"+name+"\n"+"Age :"+age+"\n"+"Address :"+address+"\n");

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    }

    c.close();
    db.close();
    db=null;

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist));
}
          }
```

Comment: :omg....thank you so much man...since morning i have been cracking my head how to do it....and how can we send this database some other server

Comment: I'm sorry i dint understand... Please dont forget to click on the accept button if the post was helpful

Comment: :my sir just asked me to send the database file to the server by providing ip addr of the server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6523761/1105585 .... do u mind accepting my answer now

Answer (score 0):

From what i have understood i think you can use **Like Clause**

eg:

```
   " SELECT * FROM Student WHERE City LIKE '"+ keyWord +%'"
```

Comment: i tried but i didnt work...it shows bland window with no data at all.....is there any other method to do so

Answer (score 0):

Replace Cursor c=MYdatabase.rawQuery("SELECt * FROM Student", null);
 with Cursor c=MYdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id=" + ID, null);

Retrieve the ID from the EditText using editText.getText().toString(); and pass it as an argument while you are quering the database.

Comment: :thank you...how to pass edittext as argument whike querin the database

Comment: Create a String object by name ID which will hold the editText value. and pass it to this Cursor c=MYdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id=" + ID, null);

Comment: is there any other way to do a search in the database

Comment: Try to understand the code snippet I have posted and implement

Comment: ok...if my string is user and edittext is et...user=et.getText().toString();..is what i used and   c=MYdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM Student WHERE NAME='"+user+"'", null); is the cursor code...is there any wrong in my code?