# How to connect MySQL server via PHP from Android Application?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, listview

I am developing an android application where some songs are stored in a server. I have to show those files in the main screen in a `ListView`. When the user clicks on any of the song it should play that song in a *Media Player*.

I have this working locally (from files on an SD card) but I want to place those files on a server. I have tried lots of examples from Google but I am not getting those properly.

Any one knows How to Connect to a MySQL Server via PHP then Plase help me out...

Comment: You can find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6525396/1531132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find nice tutorial here

[How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Hi @Ram That example showing the msg like unexpectedly application stopped . when I add Product in database 3 extra copies of the product showing.....

Comment: that's the example for the beginner level, It just guides us for new application..

Comment: did u executed that application?

Comment: ya. but not directly run the downloaded code. I followed the way.