# How to save in values server in JSON android

Tags: android, json

```
http://www.slicapp.com/slic/edit_profile.php?message=[{&email1=arun&email2=gggg&email3=gg&facebook=ffg&twitter=ddgg&gplus=ffdd&youtube=fdd&linkedin=gff&instagram=gfg&tumblr=aa}]
```

i have to upload data on server by click on save buttton ho to do this in android

i am new and need urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your android application, you need to do the following:

- Build a JSONObject with values
- Send this to your server through HttpPost

And on your server, you need a php file which will receive this object, parse it and insert the values into an sql database. It is as important to have the php code right as much as the android code.

You will get a lot of tutorials if you google this. Some of the first few results when I googled this now are:
http://androidforums.com/application-development/297822-sending-json-server.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

A similar question has been asked multiple times. Have a look at this: [Send data from android to server via JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523761/send-data-from-android-to-server-via-json)