# Best way to export data to mySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

What is the **Best** way to export a bunch of strings from an android app to a mySQL database?

I've looked all over the place. All over here and all over the internet. I have found a bunch of different answers but nothing really makes sense.

Should I use an AsyncTask or a HTTPclient? I also looked at the Microsoft JDBC database export but that also didn't really make any sense to me. Thanks for any help.

edit: I need to add the data to the mySQL database table.

Comment: What do you mean by export?  Do you mean you want to add data from your app to a MySQL db?  Are you basically looking for a way to directly connect to MySQL from Android?

Comment: yes i need to add the strings to different fields in the database table. So yes i guess i just need to connect to the database

Comment: Looking at similar questions, it seems that it isn't possible. What you'd want to do is post the data to web service (basically a PHp script or whatever) which would then add the data to the databases.  Essentially the same as submitting a form on a website.

Comment: Ok. That was my back up plan. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with JDBC connector and JDBC API. I've tested with connector mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar and works perfect and fast. You'll need an asynctask for this or a Runnable in own thread to avoid locking UI thread and risking killing your apk.

Check here [for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810116/android-mysql-using-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/6554930#6554930)