# How to connect to a SQLite on network from Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Just wondering whether it's possible to directly access a SQLite database on the network from Android?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I would avoid such design.

Comment: its a simple application. one data entry form that's all

Comment: @kakopappa, Have you found solution for this? with Sqlite?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently there is a way you can connect to MySQL using mysql-jdbc-driver.

[Android + MySQL using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810116/android-mysql-using-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it is possible directly. You can host some kind of service on the network. Call/Access that service from android and pass it the data you want to store in a database. That service would be responsible for storing data on android's behalf in network database.