# Android and online databases

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, rest

I'm developing an Android application which helps doctors to manage their appointment schedules.  An example of an activity which will be carried out is if a doctor will be late he will adjust the time that he is going to be late and all appointments will be postponed to match that timing. Appointment holders (patients) will be notified via SMS.

I want to create an online database so that the doctors can access the database via the app through any location. **Is it possible for me to access this through SQlite. And if so what are steps that I need to follow to create the database.**

I'm aware that the task can be done with the use of web services and JDBC. But I can't figure out how this should be done

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: You need web services. What about them don't you understand? Server or client side?

Comment: I need to know how the database needs to be created online and how it can be accessed through web services. :)  Thank you for taking time to help me

Comment: [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998749/using-mysql-with-android/13002532#13002532) i hope this would help

Comment: Have u done with the appointment app? @TeshEms

Answer (score 0):

Prefer URL :

[Android Web Service Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588311/android-web-service-tutorial)

For .net webservice :

http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html