# Android : How to send data to remote database without using PHP or any webservices?

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to send data from android application to localhost MySQL database. I have created application in JAVA and it works fine. But the same code doesn't work in android. What is the issue. Below is the code for the android.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private Connection conn = null;  
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
private String dbName = "testDB";
private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
private String userName = "root"; 
private String password = "";   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the database");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO test " +
                "VALUES ('XYZ')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 

        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I am getting error as:

```
04-01 12:52:31.114: W/System.err(910): java.sql.SQLException: Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception: java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:3306 - Connection refused
04-01 12:52:31.114: W/System.err(910): ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
04-01 12:52:31.114: W/System.err(910): java.net.SocketException
04-01 12:52:31.114: W/System.err(910): MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:3306 - Connection refused
04-01 12:52:31.114: W/System.err(910): STACKTRACE:
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910): java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:3306 - Connection refused
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:143)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:225)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1805)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:191)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:226)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at com.example.getip.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 12:52:31.124: W/System.err(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 12:52:31.134: W/System.err(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 12:52:31.134: W/System.err(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 12:52:31.134: W/System.err(910):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 12:52:31.134: W/System.err(910): ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
04-01 12:52:31.144: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1875)
04-01 12:52:31.144: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
04-01 12:52:31.144: W/System.err(910):  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:191)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:226)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at com.example.getip.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 12:52:31.156: W/System.err(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 12:52:31.164: W/System.err(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 12:52:31.164: W/System.err(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 12:52:31.164: W/System.err(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 12:52:31.164: W/System.err(910):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is your device/emulator and your database on the same network

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/: here localhost means system on which program is running in ur case it is android device, u need to give ip of system on which mysql is installed

Comment: @Atrix1987 i am trying in emulator.

Comment: @ChanchalShelar can i give the ip like this jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/:

Comment: @sachi yes, but as u said ur trying in emulator, is it on same system as Mysql?

Comment: @ChanchalShelar yes. Both are in same machine. please help me. I am stuck here.

Comment: @sachi k, relax, allow me 15 mins.. will try on my system and will be back

Comment: @sachi meanwhile check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810116/android-mysql-using-com-mysql-jdbc-driver and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc

Comment: @ChanchalShelar ok. waiting for your response.

Comment: @ChanchalShelar hi i solved that in emulator using your links. I need to specify url like jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/dbname. Now can i use my url like this using my device jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/dbname or do i need to make any changes.

Comment: @sachi try it, possibly will work else check ip on mysql system using 'ipconfig' adn add that ip, as ip ur using is local ip for system

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27311/discussion-between-chanchal-shelar-and-sachi)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by replacing localhost with 10.0.2.2