# How to connect an android app with database?

Tags: android, database

I am a beginner in android app development I'm planning to bring my website to android app so i want to connect the app to the mysql database of my website.Tell me how to do that?? which is the best way to do tat??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some details about what you have tried so far, and maybe we can help you with any problems you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have some info about the topic:

[How to connect Android app to MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732853/how-to-connect-android-app-to-mysql-database)

http://www.trustingeeks.com/connect-android-app-to-mysql-database/

Using JDBC driver to connect to DB: [Android + MySQL using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810116/android-mysql-using-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Not only you can find useful tips about the topic but also exact files with changes.